# Sun and other lighting isn't working in blender render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to add lighting to this scene but whenever I put a sun, etc, the sun does nothing. Please help.[image]

[image]

Comment: could you upload the blend file ? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you add more information about the task are you would like to achieve? Are you referring to the material/textured view or the render? Are you able to see them in the default scene, or every scene you try have this problem?

Comment: Is it possible that the camera is inside a wall, and therefor cannot see anything?

Comment: I added the download